# Instantiating storyboard programmatically in appdelegate

Tags: ios, storyboard, ios7, appdelegate

I decided to use different storyboards for ios6 and and ios7 and so I need to instantiate storyboards in code. I have this method in the app delegate´s `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

but nothing happens, it always just instantiate the storyboard named `iPadStoryboard`when run on the iPad simulator, I have deleted the Main interface´s from the info.plist. Any idea what´s happening here?

```
- (void)loadStoryboards
{
    CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0"))

        NSLog(@"1");
        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
        {
            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone-ios5" bundle:nil];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"loading iPad storyboard");
            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadStoryboardOS6" bundle:nil];
        }

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))

        NSLog(@"2");
        if (iOSDeviceScreenSize.height == 480)
        {

            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        } else {
            mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPadStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        }


    self.initialViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.initialViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing some braces around both system version checks.

Comment: neilco: thank you so much! missing those creates some real weird behavior.

Comment: No worries, @tom-lilletveit. Code inside an if statement should always be in braces if it's multi-line. In fact, as a general style rule, I say all if statements should use braces. I find it helps readability.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to make sure that the mainStoryboard is assigned to the iPadStoryboardOS6?

Answer (score 1):

Be careful how you check for iPad. 480px screen height doesn't cover iPhone5. Use:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
```